# Información De Discos Linux a Bases De datos Mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, shell-script

Alguien quien me pueda ayudar por favor..
Necesito por medio de un Shell de linux, almacenar la información cada 1 hora del los volúmenes de linux  y enviarlos a una bases de datos mysql

Mil gracias..

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.